# macOS & AppleScript: Save email attachment in folder and assign tag

Tags: macos, applescript

I've written a AppleScript which I would like to run via a rule in the macOS mail app.
The script is supposed to do the following:

1. Wait 10 seconds to make sure all emails are downloaded
2. Check if new emails come with PDF attachments
3. If so, save them to a specified folder
4. If this folder does not exist: create it
5. Assign a tag to the saved PDF

However it does not do anything and I just can't find out why. I couldn't find anything in the console and the folder permissions seems to be OK as well.

Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Julius

```
delay 10
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        repeat with theMessage in theMessages
            tell application "Mail"
                repeat with theAttachment in mail attachments of theMessage
                    set attachmentName to name of theAttachment
                    if attachmentName ends with ".pdf" then
                        set saveFolder to "/Users/username/Desktop/Aktuelles"
                        log "Save folder: " & saveFolder
                        tell application "Finder"
                            if not (exists folder saveFolder) then
                                log "Creating folder: " & saveFolder
                                make new folder at (path to desktop folder) with properties {name:"Aktuelles"}
                            end if
                            set newFile to (make new file at folder saveFolder with properties {name:attachmentName})
                            log "New file path: " & POSIX path of newFile
                            set file type of newFile to "PDF "
                            set creation date of newFile to (current date)
                            set modification date of newFile to (current date)
                            set tags of newFile to "Aktuell"
                            log "File tags: " & tags of newFile
                        end tell
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of nuances that you didn’t take into account, but it’s OK that you immediately tried to take the bull by the horns (start with the difficult one). 1) Only the Mail.app application itself can save attachments to disk. 2) Plain AppleScript can only set tags in a limited way, so it's better to use AsObjC. 3) The tag must already be in the Finder settings (must be added there manually if it's non-standard). 4) Scripting additions commands (Posix path, current date)) inside a Finder tell-block should not be used.

I wrote you a script that works. But still, keep in mind that there is one more important nuance: **my script does not check for the presence of prohibited characters in the name of the attached file**. Such files will simply be ignored. You yourself can take into account such cases if necessary. My script just assumes the name is legitimate.

```
use AppleScript version "2.3.1"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

set actuellesHFS to ((path to desktop) as Unicode text) & "Aktuelles:"
tell application "Finder" to if not (exists folder actuellesHFS) then make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"Aktuelles"}
delay 10

using terms from application "Mail"
    -- on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with aMessage in (get selection)
            tell aMessage to set mailAttachments to mail attachments
            if (count mailAttachments) > 0 then tell aMessage to repeat with anAttachment in mailAttachments
                set aName to (name of anAttachment) as Unicode text
                if aName ends with ".pdf" then
                    set a to actuellesHFS & aName
                    save anAttachment in (a as «class furl»)
                    set posixPath to POSIX path of (a as alias)
                    tell me to setTags:{"Orange"} forPath:posixPath
                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
    -- end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from

on setTags:tagList forPath:posixPath -- set the tags, replacing any existing
    set aURL to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:posixPath -- make URL
    aURL's setResourceValue:tagList forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
end setTags:forPath:
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations and your effort. I went through your script and edited the tag "Orange" to a tag that already exists on my system.

However, te script doesn't seem to do what I was hoping it would. The PDFs are not appearing in the specified folder. I can't find any error messages either.
What could be a next step?

Comment: The script is mail rule's action. So, save it in **/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/** folder of home. Then, in Mail.app go --> Preferences--> Rules. Create new rule and assign this script as action. Then, wait until you will receive some message with PDF attachments inside. Google "Mail rules creating" for more help.

Comment: Yes sure. That’s what I did.

Comment: Note: I edited 2 code lines in the script. So? When you don't have Actuells folder on the desktop, the rule creates it when you open the Mail.app? New messages for rule should exist as well.

Comment: Again, I’m really grateful for your help and efforts. 
However, I can’t get it to work. I’ve double checked everything and don’t know how I could further continue debugging this. 
Any ideas are much appreciated

Comment: I don't know why the EDITED script (see above) which works fine using Mail.app selection, doesn't work as rule. Note if the sender sends you PDF with read/only permissions, you can't set the tag until you reset permissions to read/write.

Comment: It seems, mail attachments can't be retrieved from **messages theMessages for rule theRule**. Because they are not "already processed" by Mail.app message objects. One possible workaround I see is: 1) the rule moves this messages as is to some PDFMessages folder (create it manually in your Mail.app), 2) the rule runs AppleScript on messages of this PDFMessages folder of Mail.app to save PDFs, 3) the rule deletes every processed message from this folder.